# How to tokenize a corpus for lemmatization?

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, tokenize, corpus

I need to lemmatize a corpus(specifically Brown corpus). What is the method to proceed?

I used the `brown.paras()` method to get a list of the paragraphs and store it in a variable.

```
list1 = brown.paras()
```

This is my output for the `list1` variable

```
[[['The', 'Fulton', 'County', 'Grand', 'Jury', 'said', 'Friday', 'an', 'investigation', 'of', "Atlanta's", 'recent', 'primary', 'election', 'produced', '``', 'no', 'evidence', "''", 'that', 'any', 'irregularities', 'took', 'place', '.']], [['The', 'jury', 'further', 'said', 'in', 'term-end', 'presentments', 'that', 'the', 'City', 'Executive', 'Committee', ',', 'which', 'had', 'over-all', 'charge', 'of', 'the', 'election', ',', '``', 'deserves', 'the', 'praise', 'and', 'thanks', 'of', 'the', 'City', 'of', 'Atlanta', "''", 'for', 'the', 'manner', 'in', 'which', 'the', 'election', 'was', 'conducted', '.']], ...]
```

I need to tokenize this, lower case the tokens and lemmatize it

Comment: So, is your question reduced to compute sentence lemmatization?

Comment: @sentence Essentially. But I am not able to tokenize, lower case and lemmatize in the normal way. When I try to do that, it shows me an error. cause it expects a string and the data type of list1(my variable) is ```nltk.corpus.reader.util.ConcatenatedCorpusView``` So, what do I exactly do in this situation?

Comment: In order to be on the same page, you should provide an example of the input you have and the output you would like to achieve.

Comment: Okay. This is a part of my assignment. So what we have to do is we have to tokenize, lowercase and lemmatize this corpus. And Use this corpus to find out the number of paragraphs the key, which is a tuple of string, appears in. So then, if the number of paragraphs(frequency) of any one of the word in the pair(key) is less than 5, we have to remove the entry from the dictionary

Comment: This is the dictionary sample ```[{('love', 'sex'): '6.77',
  ('tiger', 'cat'): '7.35',
  ('tiger', 'tiger'): '10.00',
  ('book', 'paper'): '7.46',
  ('computer', 'keyboard'): '7.62',
  ('computer', 'internet'): '7.58',
  ('plane', 'car'): '5.77',
  ('train', 'car'): '6.31',
  ('telephone', 'communication'): '7.50',
  ('television', 'radio'): '6.77',
  ('media', 'radio'): '7.42',
  ('drug', 'abuse'): '6.85',
  ('bread', 'butter'): '6.19',
  ('cucumber', 'potato'): '5.92',
  ('doctor', 'nurse'): '7.00',
. . .```

Comment: And the output should also be a dictionary with the unwanted keys removed.